# How is Debt to Equity ratio calculated in moneycontrol and screener.in?

Tags: financial-statements, ratio

I am trying to understand how Debt to Equity is calculated in websites such as [moneycontrol.com](https://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/sterlitetechnologies/ratiosVI/ST20#ST20) and [screener.in](https://www.screener.in/company/STRTECH/consolidated/)

**For e.g,** if we look at Debt/Equity for STRTECH for Mar 2018, it's shown as 1 in both the websites.

**Following is the balance sheet details of STRTECH for Mar 2018**

[image]

Now, by looking at the actual numbers, I see that the numbers are as follows:

**Total Debt**: 2313.86
**Total Equity**: 1069.99
Therefore, **Debt to Equity = 2313.86/1069.99 = 2.16**

I am unable to understand how the moneycontrol and screener websites gets 1 as the ratio.

Comment: Which calculation don't you understand, the last one?  If so, subtract Total Liabilities from Total Equity & Liabilities to get the Total Equity and then divide the Total Liabilities by that.

Comment: Financial sources such as moneycontrol.com and screener.in shows that the Debt/Equity is 1. I am trying to see how they came to that answer since I am getting 2.

Comment: @BobBaerker why "*subtract Total Liabilities from Total Equity & Liabilities to get the Total Equity*", when Total Equity is already explicitly listed as 1,069.99?

Comment: @RonJohn - I was just guessing at which calculation the OP didn't understand and I shouldn't have done that.  It's clear now that I should leave this one for you to solve :->)

Comment: Possibly – I'm not an accountant – they're just using borrowings for debt, not all liabilities. Borrowings = 616.22 + 462.74 = 1,078.96 which divided by 1069.99 gives 1.008.